# Question about feasibility of LINQ using inheritance

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

If I have a base class B and inheriting child class C1 and C2, can I use LINQ to map C1 and C2 to corresponding tables T1 and T2 if B contains some common fields?

Comment: How about using Entity Framework instead? - Linq to SQL was abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to SQL only supports table-per-hierarchy inheritance out of the box. Entity Framework allows different storage schemes including table-per-subclass as you describe.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161164.aspx#_Toc188851307) may help.